# Selenium C# Webdriver Dropdown Doesn't Fire Javascript

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Seleniunm to test my webpage.

I have a dropdown box that I want to select an option for. This fires off some Ajax that gets some data for the relevant units.

This works fine when I view the page normally, but with selenium it changes the option in the text box but the Ajax isn't triggered.

Markup on page:

```html
<select id="measure" name="measure">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Metric</option>
    <option value="2">US Imperial</option>
    <option value="3">UK Imperial</option>
</select>
```

C# code:

```
var dropDown = WebDriver.FindElementById("measure");
var selectElement = new SelectElement(dropDown);
selectElement.SelectByValue("3");
```

What am I missing in terms of selecting/clicking the dropdown option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the FirefoxDriver instead of the InternetExplorer Driver and all seems fine now.

Comment: I'm using the FirefoxDriver right now and it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue just recently using the FirefoxDriver. In my particular setup, I had a bubbling delegated "change" event handler on the `<html>` tag that wasn't firing:

```js
document.documentElement.addEventListener("change", handleChange, false);

function handleChange(event) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The following code wasn't triggering an onchange even on a dropdown:

```
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);

select.SelectByText("Foo");
```

The option would get selected, but no change even was triggered -- even upon setting focus to another form field. I had use my own mouse select a new value in the dropdown before a change event would get triggered.

I fixed this issue by clicking on the dropdown, then clicking on the option inside it:

```
IWebElement element = // ...

element.Click();

element.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))
       .Single(opt => opt.Text == Value)
       .Click();
```

Here's a handy extension method that does the same:

```
public static class IWebElementExtensions
    /// <summary>
    /// Selects an option in a dropdown list by visible option text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="element"></param>
    /// <param name="optionText"></param>
    public static void SelectOptionByText(this IWebElement element, string optionText)
    {
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

        if (element.TagName != "select")
            throw new ArgumentException("The element must be a <select> tag");

        if (optionText == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("optionText");

        var options = element.FindElements(By.TagName("option"))
                             .Where(opt => opt.Text == optionText);

        if (options.Count() == 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Could not find <option>" + optionText + "</option> inside <select id=\"" + element.GetAttribute("id") + "\">");

        if (options.Count() > 1)
            throw new WebDriverException("Too many <option>" + optionText + "</option> tags inside <select id=\"" + element.GetAttribute("id") + "\">");

        element.Click();
        options.Single().Click();
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
element.SelectOptionByText("Foo");
```

**Benefits**

- No JavaScript hacks
- Uses native events in Selenium

**Drawbacks**

- Takes a little longer to execute

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using jQuery works better than WebDriver's SelectElement class.

Try this.  Notice how I'm calling the jQuery .change event (JavaScript onchange event).  I have another dropdown that depends on this dropdown, so in order for the dependent dropdown to populate, I have to call that event.  In order to get that to work, I also had to enable Native Events for my Firefox driver.  I see you're selecting by value, not by option text.  You should be able to modify my jQuery code with code that works for selecting by value.  Also, if you're working with ASP.NET controls, using WebDriver's code won't work well because the id is dynamic based on the browser.  So you'll have to grab the id via jQuery using client id.  I pasted that code below also if that is the case for you.

```
public static void SetDropdownSelectedOptionValue(IWebDriver driver, string tagId, string newValue)
{
    //new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("book-country_id"))).SelectByText(newValue);

    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    js.ExecuteScript("$('#" + tagId + " option:contains(" + newValue + ")').attr('selected', 'selected')");
    js.ExecuteScript("$('#" + tagId + "').change()");
    //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Config.WAIT_TIME));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Required if calling the onchange native event.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.EnableNativeEvents = true;
```

If using ASP.NET controls, use this jQuery code rather than the explicit id.  Of course modify this code to put tagId in between to get the jQuery selector.

```
$('#<%=dropdownid.ClientID %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution I could come up with to deal with a Formkit select that would not fire the form change when the option was selected. Below is the only solution I could come up with. It isn't bulletproof but it has work.

This solution uses Actions. Check this link for more information:
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/action-class-in-selenium

Note: Try manipulating the form using the down arrow and enter key before implementing this solution. If it doesn't work manually it won't work programmatically.

Another Note: This solution assumes another option hasn't already been selected. If you want to handle the case where another option has already been selected you have to find the index of the selected option as well as the option you want and manipulate the form accordingly.

```
var selectorBy = sharedStepSupport.GetSelectorBy(selector, selectorType); //A custom method that builds the selector By.

var selectPreScroll = webDriver.FindElement(selectorBy);
webDriver.ScrollToElement(selectPreScroll); //A custom scroll method
var select = webDriver.FindElement(selectorBy);

Thread.Sleep(250);
select.Click();
var options = select.FindElements(By.TagName("option")).Where(opt => opt.Enabled == true); //Gets all interactable options as some are disabled and aren't presented.

for (int i = 0; i < options.Count(); i++)
{
    var text = options.ElementAt(i).Text;
    if (text == optionText)
    {
        optionIndex = i;
        i = options.Count();
    }
}
Actions actions = new Actions(webDriver); //Actions allows a series of actions to be built and performed. This can be a really useful tool for those doing automation.
for (int i = 0;i <= optionIndex; i++)
{
    actions.SendKeys(Keys.Down);
}
actions.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
actions.Build();
actions.Perform();
```